# File Explorer keeps crashing on open?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

I have seen similar questions around but the answers are not helping, so here my question. I recently changed my working-nicely Windows 7 into 10 and... works fine except when I try to open (file) Explorer in almost any way.

Since this seems to be a recurring problem, I have tried few things:

1. Run SFC (all files seen to be fine)
2. Unistall (and think deleted) the graphics driver.
3. Giving full control to the users in all the partitions.
4. No, I do not use AutodeskInventor.
5. The Dump file is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0vjzxhengjhcf8/explorer.exe.7800.zip?dl=0.

At this point I have to admit that I do not know how to read this file but hope it will be useful for the answer, if any.

Comment: My guess: you have an Explorer extension installed that was Win7 compatible but isn't Win10 compatible.  Does it behave the same way if you boot into Safe Mode?  Is there anything related to the crashes in the Event Logs?

Answer (score 0):

The crash is caused by Adobe Acrobat 9.0 (Acrobat Elements DLL ContextMenu64.dll):

```
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000001163fc

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000000001163fc 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ContextMenu64_b370000!ShowConversionSettingsDialog+661c5
00000000`0b404cb5 488b5c2430      mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+0
00000000`001163fc ??              ???

BUGCHECK_STR:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT

APP:  explorer.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
02 ntdll!RtlReportException
03 ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode$filt$1
04 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
05 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
06 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
07 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
08 0x0
09 ContextMenu64_b370000!ShowConversionSettingsDialog
0a ContextMenu64_b370000!ShowConversionSettingsDialog
0b ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine
0c ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode
0d ntdll!LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse
0e ntdll!LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution
0f ntdll!LdrpLoadDllInternal
10 ntdll!LdrpLoadDll
11 ntdll!LdrLoadDll
12 KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW


FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:software_nx_fault_c0000005_contextmenu64.dll!showconversionsettingsdialog

    Loaded symbol image file: ContextMenu64.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat Elements\ContextMenu64.dll
    Image name: ContextMenu64.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Jun 12 08:34:11 2008 (4850C363)
    CheckSum:         00180E84
    ImageSize:        00189000
    File version:     9.0.0.332
    Product version:  9.0.0.332
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0400.04b0 0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Adobe Systems Inc.
    ProductName:      Adobe Acrobat Elements
    InternalName:     Acrobat Elements
    OriginalFilename: ContextMenu.dll
    ProductVersion:   9.0.0.2008061100\0
    FileVersion:      9.0.0.2008061100\0
    PrivateBuild:     9.0.0.2008061100\0
    SpecialBuild:     9.0.0.2008061100\0
    FileDescription:  Adobe Acrobat Context Menu
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright 1984-2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated and its licensors. All rights reserved.
    LegalTrademarks:  Copyright 1984-2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated and its licensors. All rights reserved.
    Comments:         Srini Gowthaman
```

The DLL is from 2008. Update to a newer Acrobat Version or disable the ShellExtension.

Comment: Thanks. That, indeed, was the problem. I installed a new version of Acrobat and everything seems to be running fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My win 10 is still performing fine.

Comment: ok. lick on the green icon to "close" the question.